# Java basic authorization with URLConnection

Tags: java, web-services, authorization

I'm opening a connection to WebService with an URLConnection class. I also set request property for basic authorization like this:

```
c.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + usernameAndPasswordEncoded);
```

Where c is an object of type URLConnection. So this is client side of WebService call. Now on server side I need to get username from session:

```
User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

But this won't get an username. Also if I look through debug mode, I see an anonymous userName in HttpSession object.
What to do to solve this problem, so that username is sent through client to WebService server for authorization?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you 'secured' this url in the web.xml?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thank you, I didn't really know I have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server end, you need to specify the login method in web.xml. For example,

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>My App</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Once you do that, the username should be available using `request.getRemoteUser()`.

Comment: Tnx. I had that, but I didn't have <security-constraint> defined in web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet specification provides explicit abstractions for that - what you need is [`request.getRemoteUser()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser())., or perhaps [`request.getUserPrincipal()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal())

Comment: @zigomir: then the authorization process isn't working out. See if you can find any hints in the server log.